# Facebook like as checkbox?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My customer got really cool idea, but i dont know if it possible to implement. he wants a facebook like on some form, as a checbox.

It would be much easier to get users facebook like, but i don't think this is possible?

thank you for you answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Facebook's API, you could accomplish this sort of functionality by attaching the `like` and `unlike` events to the checking and unchecking of a `checkbox`. You would of course need some custom javascript (jQuery), along the lines of:

```
$('#facebook_checkbox').click(function() {
    if( $('#facebook_checkbox:checked') ) {
        // execute API for like
    } else {
        // execute API for unlike
    }
}
```